# multiple form in symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I have a form for adding comments, and i want to know how can i multiply this form on the same page.
I tried this code but it does not work :

```
{% for statut in statuts %}
<div>
    {{ statut.sujet }}


    <form action="" method="post" {{ form_enctype(formC) }}>    
        {{ form_errors(formC) }}
        {{ form_errors(formC.commentaire) }}
        {{ form_widget(formC.commentaire) }}
        <div><input type="submit" class="btn btn-info"/><div>
        {{ form_rest(formC) }}
    </form>

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Does somebody know how to do that ? or any suggestions

Comment: i think you are looking for the collection Field Type. check this sources: [link](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/collection.html) [link](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: i don't want that but thank you anyway

Comment: Why do you think collection won't suit you? Seems like perfect tool for the job (unless there's more to it than the info you gave us)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in the controller like get all statuts then run a for loop for each statuts and get comment form for each statut field store them in array and return the array.

In your twig template then run a for loop for the same.